# Linq join on multpile columns with a where not equals condition and need to return columns from both tables

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am joining tables on two columns and need to find records where the third column does not match.

The linq query I have will return the correct records from table 1, but I am unable to select the date column from the second table.

I have tried grouping results but had trouble with the 'where not equals' condition.

So, I have these records:

**Table 1:** *4SONS, 112, 09/03/2016*

**Table 2:** *4SONS, 112, 09/26/2016*

What I need to return is - *4SONS, 112, 09/03/2016, 09/26/2016*

But my query returns only - *4SONS, 112, 09/03/2016* without a way to get that date from table 2. These are the only 3 columns in each table.

```
var query = from s in schedTable.AsEnumerable()
            where s.Field<DateTime?>("AuditDate").HasValue

            join c in completeTable.AsEnumerable()
            on new { account = s.Field<string>("Account").ToString(), store = s.Field<string>("Store").ToString()} 
            equals new { account = c.Field<string>("Account").ToString(), store = c.Field<string>("Store").ToString() }

            where s.Field<DateTime>("AuditDate").Date != c.Field<DateTime>("AuditDate").Date
            select s;

var typeD = query.ToList();
```

Comment: The result apparently cannot be list of data records. Create a class and use `select new YourClass { ... }`. Or anonymous type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you are looking for:

```
var query = from s in schedTable.AsEnumerable()
                    where s.Field<DateTime?>("AuditDate").HasValue
                    join c in completeTable.AsEnumerable()
                    on new { account = s.Field<string>("Account").ToString(), store = s.Field<string>("Store").ToString()}
                      equals new { account = c.Field<string>("Account").ToString(), store = c.Field<string>("Store").ToString()}
                    where s.Field<DateTime>("AuditDate").Date != c.Field<DateTime>("AuditDate")
                    select new {
                        account = s.Field<string>("Account"),
                        store = s.Field<string>("Store"),
                        sched = s.Field<DateTime>("AuditDate"),
                        comp = c.Field<DateTime>("AuditDate")
                    };
        var typeD = query.ToList();
```